# Как закрыть AlertDialog по нажатию на ImageView

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Нужно закрыть сообщение по нажатию на ImageView, сообщение обрабатывается в адаптере ReciclerView

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image_view, null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(PHOTO_URL)
                        .into(imageView);
                alertadd.setView(view);

                alertadd.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image_view, null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(PHOTO_URL)
       .into(imageView);
alertadd.setView(view);     

//Например, вот так:        
final Dialog dialog = alertadd.create();
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: не открывается, не закрывается или ошибка?

Comment: Ошибки нет, открытое сообщение с картинкой не закрывает

Comment: Странно. Попробовал сейчас, у меня закрывает... Возможно я не так понял вопрос. Поясните, что значит "сообщение обрабатывается в адаптере.."? Сообщение = диалог?

Comment: Сообщение выводится когда выбирается один из элементов в RecyclerView, его обработка и наполнение данными происходит в отдельном классе, так называемом адаптере

Comment: Я понял вашу задачу как: "Закрыть диалог по нажатию картинки, которая в нем отображается". А что вы на самом деле спрашивали? :)

Comment: Вы все верно поняли, но данный вами ответ не работает в моем случае, могу добавить кнопку чтобы закрывать окно, но мне нужно именно закрывать картинкой, все связанно скорее всего с адаптером, возможно вы знаете другой способ решение задачи??

Comment: у меня и из адаптера `RecyclerView` всё работает. Добавил ваш код и свой. Всё закрывается. Использую `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` может в этом дело? Вы `alertadd.show();` удалили?